# Changing advice language doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, skmaps

I'm new with Skobbler SDK and learn with the Swift Demo + the well documented tuto (http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/ios#sec01)

However, I still can't configure the advice language settings using their instructions ...

Here is my code :

```
let settings = SKAdvisorSettings()
    settings.advisorVoice =  "fr"
    settings.language  = SKAdvisorLanguage.FR
    settings.advisorType = SKAdvisorType.AudioFiles
    settings.resourcesPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath! + "/SKMaps.bundle/AdvisorConfigs/Languages"
```

The event is define by :

```
 func routingService(routingService: SKRoutingService!, didChangeCurrentAdvice currentAdvice: SKRouteAdvice!, isLastAdvice: Bool) {

    NSLog("New advice "+currentAdvice.adviceInstruction)

}
```

Si I get "in 90  meters turn right " for instance.

By the way, no audio files are played neither

Could you please give me a hand :) ? Thank you in advance

Comment: I'd like to have the result in french by the way !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in the code that is supposed to "play the audio advice" (in AudioService.m) - the name of the .mp3 file was not correctly built.

I've fixed this by making the following change:

```
func playAudioFile(audioFileName: String) { 
    var soundFilePath: String = audioFilesFolderPath + "/" + audioFileName 
    soundFilePath = soundFilePath + ".mp3" 

    if !NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(soundFilePath) 
    { 
        return 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        audioPlayer = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: soundFilePath), fileTypeHint: nil) 
        audioPlayer.delegate = self 
        audioPlayer.play() 
    } 

}
```

This affected only the swift demo and will be fixed in the next update

Comment: Yes Ando that's it :) !! Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found my mistake by replacing :

```
  settings.advisorType = SKAdvisorType.AudioFiles
```

with

```
  settings.advisorType = SKAdvisorType.TextToSpeech
```

However I still don't know how to use prerecorded files ... Even with the section "Using prerecorded files in tuto ...

Answer (score 1):

Did you set your settings as the `advisorConfigurationSettings` of your `SKRoutingService`?

```
[SKRoutingService sharedInstance].advisorConfigurationSettings = advisorSettings;
```

You will also have to set the path for the audio files like this:

```
NSBundle* advisorResourcesBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SKAdvisorResources.bundle"]];
NSString* soundFilesFolder = [advisorResourcesBundle pathForResource:@"Languages" ofType:@""];
NSString* audioFilesFolderPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/sound_files",soundFilesFolder,userLanguageCode];
[AudioService sharedInstance].audioFilesFolderPath = audioFilesFolderPath;
```

`userLanguageCode` would be `"fr"` in your case